# Can't access another model through Active Record - nil class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to ruby and to rails.

I've been stuck with this for days. I think I should be able to access a variable in a controller of one model, that is stored in another model easily?

I have four models: `User` - (1-1) - `Profile` - (1-M) - `Appointment` - (1-1) - `Option`.

Options contains `pricePerPerson` and `discount` for an appointment. Appointments contains, among others, `numPeople`. 
I want to access the figure in the `Option`s model for the `pricePerPerson` (and `discount`, if appropriate) and use it in the view show for `Appointment`s. 
(@ `<%= appointment.price = Option.pricePerPerson * numPeople %>`)

So far I haven't been able to do this and have had to resort to hard-coding a price per person. I would rather not hard-code that, if possible.

So far, the system is saying that there is nothing in  the database(nil class for price. I don't know why as I have entered a figure in this. It is skipping to the "else" section of the method. (Basically, it keeps returning 6, no matter what)

Appointments.rb Model:

```
def calculatePrice
  if option.present?
    return option.pricePerPerson*numpeople
  else
    return 6
  end
end
```

Appointments controller:

```
def show
  @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @appointment = Appointment.new
  @appointment.price
end

def create
  @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @appointment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was 
       successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @appointment }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: 
       :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Options controller:

```
def new
  @option = Option.new
end

def create
  @option = Option.new(option_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @option.save
    format.html { redirect_to @option, notice: 'Option was successfully 
     created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @option }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @option.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity 
      }
  end
 end
end
```

options.rb model:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :appointment
end
```

Database schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160703171518) do

create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "phone"
t.string   "email"
t.integer  "numpeople"
t.date     "date"
t.string   "timeslot"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "appointments", ["user_id"], name: "index_appointments_on_user_id"

create_table "options", force: :cascade do |t|
t.decimal  "pricePerPerson"
t.integer  "discount"
t.integer  "appointment_id"
t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
end

add_index "options", ["appointment_id"], name  
"index_options_on_appointment_id"

create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "firstname"
t.string   "lastname"
t.text     "address"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "phone"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "profiles", ["user_id"], name: "index_profiles_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: 
"index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Why you you need a `has_one/belongs_to` on options-appointments? In most cases this means you can store all data in one model

Comment: I agree with @Vasfed. I think you could condense this modelling down to two models and have a single one to many relationship.

Comment: please, read railsguide once

Comment: I would like to have a separate pricing model though, and I would like to understand how to do this for the future too. I have been reading some railsguides but I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments. It's likely that you can simplify your database schema.
However, should you want to stick to your schema and should you want to be able to debug your code by yourself (in simple cases), I suggest you to install the following gems in you Gemfile. When there's something wrong in your code, it will help you understand where and will display a console allowing you to test some new code.

```html
group :development, :test do
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm just worried that if I simplify the database to just appointments table, it mean i will have to hardcode the price. I want the price to be able to be changed by the admin of the site, if they decide to change the price. That's why I don't really want to simplify the tables. My plan is to add other options to the options table also, like %discount depending on the size of the group and maybe other things going forward. These things need to be set by the admin without going into the code

Comment: Ok. So that I can help you more, could you share the code that you have in your db/schema.rb file? Then, it'll be possible to fully understand how your database is currently built.

Comment: Thank you for your help in this area. I have updated my post's code to the most recent version and I have included the database schema. Would my problem be anything to do with my associations being off I wonder?

Comment: @OkiGirl: Thanks for updating your post. I checked you schema.rb file and I think most of your issues come from the way you (wrongly) built your database. Indeed, rails is built on naming conventions so things do not work well is models are badly designed (I know since might not be very clear for beginners). I'll try to make a new answer with code suggestions as soon as possible (since you'll have to make a few changes in your database).

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I'm now having trouble with action mailer. I wonder if it's a problem with the database too??

Comment: Turns out, because I'm using Cloud 9 for development, it won't allow mails to be sent out. So that's why my mails aren't delivering. However, I would still appreciate your input on my pricing issue. Can you tell me how I might have set up the database badly?